# Where can you download SOLC ( solidity compiler) from?

Tags: solidity, json-rpc

I am looking for the SOLC solidity compiler that works with JSON-RPC.

The only one I find is the one at
https://www.npmjs.com/package/solc

However its says
 "this commandline interface is not compatible with solc provided by the Solidity compiler package and thus cannot be used in combination with an Ethereum client via the eth.compile.solidity() RPC method. Please refer to the Solidity compiler documentation for instructions to install solc."

ON the Ethereum site, I cannot find a simple download page for it...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Better place to look is the Solidity docs. Here is their installation page: http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/installing-solidity.html

This includes the intructions I used to install solc on my env (ubuntu).

Answer (score 0):

Solidity executable binaries may be downloaded directly from here:

https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/releases

Currently pre-built executables are available for linux (static linked), Ubuntu linux, and Windows.

Source code is also available at the above link.

Mac binaries are not currently provided, and must be built from source.

Answer (score 0):

You can also find the static binaries at https://solc-bin.ethereum.org/

They created the [ethereum/solc-bin](https://github.com/ethereum/solc-bin/) repo to keep the releases. If you need a specific architecture, check their folders at the root level:

- emscripten-asmjs
- emscripten-wasm32
- linux-amd64
- macosx-amd64
- wasm
- windows-amd64

Each architecture lists its static versions at
`https://solc-bin.ethereum.org/{architecture}/list.json`. Eg. For wasm that is: https://binaries.soliditylang.org/wasm/list.json